# Plural or singular when referring to a team

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

> The Lions are a shadow of their former self.
>
> The Lions are a shadow of their former selves.

I am not sure if both are correct, because technically you can say "their self", but something tells me I might be wrong on this. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lions is a team.  As a team, it can be treated as a singular concept.  The team's name is a collective proper noun.  However, if it is singular, it needs to be singular throughout the context:

> The Lions *is* a shadow of *its* former *self*.

On the other hand, "the Lions" is a plural construction.  When treated as a plural concept, it remains plural throughout the context:

> The Lions *are* a shadow of *their* former *selves*.

Different dialects have different views about when it is natural to treat a collective noun as singular or plural.

I can think of only one context in which the phrasing "their self" works.  The *singular they* is used exclusively for a person, as an option that avoids the gender marking of *he* and *she*.

Comment: Agreed. In Australian English, for example, “The Brisbane Lions are a shadow of there former selves.” is certainly the correct and idiomatic form (nothing to do with whether it’s true or not - I don’t follow AFL!).

Comment: Even in the U.S., we would use *are* and *they* for a team whose name is a plural (like *the Lions*).